# error C2512: 'Tile' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, default-constructor

**Still have the error even with a default constructor.**

```
class Foo {
    public:
    Foo ( int x, int y, int type );
}
```

And in the .cpp file

```
Foo::Foo ( int x = 0, int y = 0, int type = 0 ) {
```

And yet, when I call it

```
Foo foo_array[5][5];
```

I get the error. Any reason why that may be?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713916/am-i-using-default-arguments-incorrectly/13713944#13713944

Comment: if you use a `std::vector` instead of raw array, then you can specify a default value so that you don't need to have an otherwise unnecessary (and perhaps not very meaningful) default constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the default arguments in the **declaration** of constructor. As it is, the compiler doesn't know about them when you try to create the array.

Comment: How would you do that with arrays? I thought you couldn't.

Comment: @JimHurley You don't need to do anything to the array - change the declaration of the constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you give me an example on how to do this? I thought that the ctor was the where I was doing it.

Comment: Change the declaration in the header from `Foo(int x, int y, int type);` to `Foo(int x = 0, int y = 0, int type = 0);`. You also have to **remove** the default arguments from the .cpp file; the compiler will remind you if you forget.